# Is there a way to find the window of the previous page (other tab)?

Tags: javascript, window, postmessage

If you open a link in a new tab (with MMB or right click or preferred method, however), is there a way from the new tab `window` to find the opener `window`? These don't work:

- `window.opener`
- `window.parent`

Maybe it's just not possible, since following a link usually 'overwrites' the window, so no ref is possible, but since we have tabs... maybe... a ref IS possible?

I want the opened window to do a `postMessage` to the original window to let it know the page has loaded, so the original window can update the link style.

I don't make these pages, so I don't have access to the back-end or HTML printage. Think Greasemonkey: I add JS to existing websites to improve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is intercepting the click event, grabbing the URL, and passing it to `window.open` and subsequent `postMessage` calls on the returned window object. Do you generate the page with these links?

In some browsers `window.open(url,'_blank')` will open in a tab.

Comment: The new page must `postMessage` to the old page, not the other way around. How does grabbing the URL help..? The pages are not mine, but Youtube or Stackoverflow etc. (A la greasemonkey.) Can I detect 'open in new tab' while intercepting the click? I don't want to always do `window.open`, only if I want a new tab.

Comment: Sorry my answer was somewhat gibberish, I've clarified but based on your comment it sounds like a no go. If you don't control the destination page then how do you expect to call `postMessage`?

Comment: Yeah, `open` is the only way probably =( but then I need a sure way to detect whether the click would open the link in a new tab. A normal left click shouldn't do the `open`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two solutions to your problem

## First solution : Cookies

An easy way is to set a cookie with the value of the current page everytime a link is clicked, you can use a [library like this one](https://github.com/khaliid/happy-cookies.js) to set a cookie and get it in the next page once you click like this

```
$("a").click( function () {  
    $.setCookie("currentPage",document.URL);
});
```

In the next page you just get the cookie like this

```
if($.getCookie("currentPage") != undefined )
   var previousPage = $.getCookie("currentPage");
```

## Second solution : Server-side langage

If you're using a server side langage like php, it's easy to get the url of the previous page :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
      echo "<script> var previousPage='" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "'; </script>";
?>
```

And finally, to post a message you just need to test if the `previousPage` variable is set:

```
if(previousPage != undefined)
{
   // Code to post your message
}
```

Comment: What do I do with `previousPage`? I don't care about the URL. I need its `window` object to send a message to it. At least one of us doesn't understand.

Comment: @Rudie do you own the page that you want to get its window object ??

Comment: No. Both pages are on the same domain. Greasemonkey style, so I'm extending existing websites like Youtube and Stackoverflow etc.